# copy certain columns from table a and insert into table b?

Tags: php, mysql

please can someone help i have been working on this query for hours. i am trying to copy certain columns from my table ptb_registrations and insert them as a new row into ptb_users.

my ptb_registrations table looks like this:

```
id  |   username  |  password   | firstname   |  lastname   |   email 

1        dave        password       james          tanner       email@email.com
2        jonx10      gundam00       eric           davies       something@email.com
3        33csgge     henry10        daniel         gilmart      mail@inbox.com
```

from these columns i only want to insert id, firstname, lastname, email and password NOT username.

So my ptb_user table looks like this:

```
   id   | user_id  |  password   | firstname   |  lastname   |   email 

    1        1        password       james          tanner       email@email.com
    2        2        gundam00       eric           davies       something@email.com
    3        3        henry10        daniel         gilmart      mail@inbox.com
```

id is an auto increment value, and i want user_id to have the same value as the auto_incremented id column when the data is inserted too (if this is possible so where id is 1 - user_id will be 1 also)

so far i have tried loads of different ways to get the columns inserted from ptb_registrations and into ptb_users but nothing is working for me.

cans someone please show me where i am going wrong, thank you.

```
 // Make a safe query
    $query ="insert into ptb_users(id, first_name)
    select ptb_registrations.id, ptb_registrations.firstname
    from ptb_registrations, temp
    where ptb_users.id=temp.id;
    ";

    mysql_query($query)or die('Could not update members: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to guarantee that your new `AUTO_INCREMENT` will match your previous user ID's... What happens if there is a break in the sequence? Your best bet is to re-assign the new table's id after you've inserted the records.

Your query should something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ptb_user (user_id, password, firstname, lastname, email)
SELECT id, password, firstname, lastname, email
FROM ptb_registrations
ORDER BY id
```

P.S. I hope you're not saving the passwords in ***plain-text***.